# When Should I Use Symbols in a Proof?

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

The question I'm about to ask might sound weird, I hope i can deliver the idea.

I have noticed that in some mathematics books (especially English ones) the proofs are written in words and symbols are used only when necessary, example: for all, implies, there exists, if and only if... etc, but in other books symbols are used more, example: $\implies$, $\forall$, $\exists$, $\iff$... etc

** So is there a rule that should be followed here? Or is it a choice that the writer makes? Will it be familiar if the proofs are mostly written with symbols?

I am asking this question because, right now, I am translating a book to English, and the writer of the original book barely used words in proofs, he only used connectors like: Therefore, Hence, Thus... etc. I do not want to translate over 300 pages for nothing.

** So should I keep the original proofs? Or should I reformulate them?

Sorry for the long question, but I am really confused here, I would be grateful if you help me.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: It's the writer's choice, but sometimes it's easier to read proofs with more words and fewer symbols

Comment: I would only use symbols if necessary. For example, for proving that there are infinitely many primes, a symbol $N=p_1\cdots p_n+1$ is probably enough.

Comment: I would consider it a question of style. If you translate a text, I would say that you should normally respect the style of the original author. Having said this, there might be exceptions... like everywhere else, you might decide top translate more freely. Given that you ask this question at all, I would however recommend to stick to the original proofs since getting the language details correct, and in math they have to be correct, is not trivial

Comment: Writers choice.  If you are translating keep the original proofs.  Do *not* reformulate.  It is dishonest otherwise.....  However when writing proofs my rule of thumb is err on the side of fewer symbols.

Comment: Changing proofs is *revising*, not merely *translating*. If you're getting paid specifically for the latter, then your clients (and/or readers) may not appreciate the former. Moreover, by adding words, you're speaking for the author; this could be problematic if you lack the author's expertise and intuition about the topic. An option is to *annotate*: make generous use of (potentially-lengthy) side- and foot-notes. (I'm recalling translations I've seen of ancient Greek works. The text itself strives to be faithful, but notes commonly provide a modern spin to the topic at hand.)

Comment: Thank you all, I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: My favorite author wrote about math books: "An elegant author says in two lines what another writes in an entire page. But if a reader has to think an hour about those two lines, while he would have read the page in five minutes, then it wasn't the correct *kind* of elegance for that reader". Meaning: If your reader can read and understand the symbols quicker than the text, then use symbols. Otherwise use text.

Comment: You might be interested in some notes (pdf) by Don Knuth and others on how to write mathematics: http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/reviewing-papers/knuth_mathematical_writing.pdf .  Don is an experienced writer and has, I think, some good advice to share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the original style. You will respect the author's intent, and, more importantly, you will avoid introducing errors due to possible misunderstandings or clumsy rewrites. As a bonus, you don't have to translate the symbols, they are international.

Comment: Okay, I was just concerned that the readers might not find it comfortable. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The readers should find it as comfortable or uncomfortable as the original ! [Unless your task is different from a pure translation, such as popularization.]

Comment: The writer said that I can change things if they are not suitable, he said that because he doesn't speak English, so he wanted to give me more space to translate more freely. But his way of writing was so raw because the topic is so theoretic and abstract, that's why symbols seem necessary.

Comment: @TarekAcila: if you don't understand his writings, don't touch them !